# implementing a search function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to implement a search function for my gridview. My codebehind looks like this

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = TextBoxSearchTitle.Text;
        string artist = TextBoxSearchArtist.Text;
        string genre = DDLSearch.SelectedValue;
        if (genre == "Alle")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = String.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' AND Artist LIKE '%{1}%' AND Genre ='{2}'", title, artist, genre);
            //figure out if table will be empty and do something...

        }
    }
```

and is running without problems so far. Only thing i dont like is when the search doesnt have any results there is no gridview shown. I want to either show an empty gridview in that case and a message "No results" or something or just a message. But i cant figure out how to  determine whether my sqldatasource object is empty or not with that filterexpression. So please help me on that one.

And also is it possible to show an empty gridview to the user if the filter expression results in an empty sqldatasource?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Empty data template for grid view.

```
  <ASP:GridView runat="server" ID="myGridView">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Search result not found
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </ASP:GridView>
```